# Is the linear transformation $T: M_{22} \to R^2$, $ T(A) = A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the linear transformation $T: M_{22} \to R^2$,  $T(A) = A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ an isomorphism?

I have the solution which is that $ker(T)$ contains more than $0$ so it is not one-to-one, and therefore, not an isomorphism. But I'm also wondering if we can just say that $T$ is not an isomorphism because $dim(M_{22}) \ne dim(R^2)$ If we cannot, is it because matrix $A$ is arbitrary so it does not necessarily have dimension of 4?

Comment: Of course, you can say that the dimensions  are not equal hence the isomorphism cannot exist. As for matrix $A$, if it has non zero kernel, it can't be an isomorphism anyway.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Then can vector spaces with equal dimensions have no isomorhpism?

Comment: Vector spaces with equal dimensions, say $n$ are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence it follows that vector spaces of same finite dimension are always isomorphic, there will be some function that will be an isomorphism between them. As a matter of fact, "suckatmath" doesn't seem appropriate, you're asking the right questions so far. Change that to "rockatmath" next time you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for any linear transformation $T$, we can say that $T$ is not an isomorphism if  the domain and codomain of $T$ do not have the same dimension.